# How can I add my own application into system notifications?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

On Tizen Wearable, when I copy images from phone to watch, after the operation is finished there is a notification which applies an **Open app** button:

[image]

(How) can I achieve the same if all below are true:

```
 - I do have my own application on the Android which posts a notification and
 - I do receive notifications from my Android application on my watch
 - I do have my own application on my watch (which should open on that *Open app* button click?
```

I know how can I create notifications from Tizen application.

What I am looking for is the way to customize the system notification in case it can be handled by my Tizen app (which is only in case the notification is originated from my phone app).

Comment: Hello, "Open App" notification is created by Gallery app of Watch, instead of Companion (Android). If you have an Watch application, i think.. you can do it by using App Control (https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/app-management/app-controls/) and Notification Ex functions - noti_ex_action_app_control_create() from https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/5.5/group__NOTIFICATION__EX__MODULE.html

Comment: This makes sense, thx. Is it somehow possible to *enhance* a notification (when originally created on Android) to make it retrievable/modifiable by my watch application? (even if it travelled through the world via Samsung servers?)

Comment: I could modify my Android app to **not** post the notification in case it **can** connect to the Watch via *SAP*, then on watch I can modify my watch app to handle the SAP message internally and post a notification (just as Gallery does seem doing it). But in this case: a.) I can lose notifications (as the phone won't have them) and b.) won't solve if the watch gets is not connected to phone (I'm out for running).

Comment: @LunchBasketball: how exactly is that Gallery app on Watch working? When I start copying images from the phone, the Gallery app is not opened on the Watch. Do you know which component can make it run? In case it's a SAP provider|consumer, it still needs to either being in foreground or running in background to receive SAP messages, no? There are pretty much no information on this topic online :(

Comment: Or, the other way around: if gallery app is not running, how can it post a notification?

Comment: App control seems no relation with SAP, or I miss something?